# CPU-Z, AIDA32 and hwinfo detect different chipsets on the same machine

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, chipset, hardware-detection, cpu-z

Previously I was posting [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/1526976/lenovo-g550-cpu-upgrade-from-t3000-to-p8700-issue), where I determined my Lenovo G550 laptop's chipset by `sudo hwinfo | grep Chipset` command:

```
  E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub
  E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
  E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
  <6>[    7.253812] pci 0000:00:00.0: Intel GM45 Chipset
  Model: "Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"
  Device: pci 0x2a43 "Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"
  Model: "Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub"
  Device: pci 0x2a40 "Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub"
  Model: "Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"
  Device: pci 0x2a42 "Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller"
```

It said that my chipset is `Intel GM45` if I am understanding it correctly.

But yesterday I've downloaded Windows based Live CD with CPU-Z and AIDA and they detected `GL40` chipset.

Also, AIDA32 said, that maximum memory I could insert into my slots is 4Gb, but I inserted 8Gb, AIDA32 and CPU-Z show it also and it laptop with 8Gb RAM works now without issues. To check if additional 4Gb is used, I've disabled `swap` and opened a lot of browsers' tabs and different applications to achieve 4.7Gb memory load.

Who says the truth - CPU-Z and AIDA32 or `hwinfo`? Or, maybe, I misunderstood something and they both show correct information?

Comment: You cannot determine all specs using software. Instead, look at the specs from the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In my case CPU-Z and AIDA32 determined my Chipset correctly, but `hwinfo` was wrong. I've disassembled my laptop, take out cooling system and looked at my GPU chip. There were text with GL40.

And it turns out, that Lenovo G550 with GL40 chipset could support 8Gb RAM.